# How to programmatically set focus on a row in a WinForms DataGrid when selecting it?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a WinForms DataGrid (not DataGridView). When I manually select a row, the row indicator, shown in the first image below, shows on the selected rows. However, if I set the DataGrid's datasource after a save and programmatically select the second row using:
`datagrid.Select(1)`, the second row gets the highlighted background color but the focus indicator is on the first row as shown in the second image below.

Is there a way to make the selected row get focus and have the indicator display for the row?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the old [System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8), the Row selection method is slightly different than the DataGridView's.

You can select a Row, as you're doing, with the [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.select) method.
This doesn't change the Current Row. To make a Row the Current, you can use the [CurrentRowIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid.currentrowindex) property.
Combined, these two move the selection and set the Current Row.

```
 // Selects and highlights the Row at index 1
 dataGrid.Select(1);
 // Make the Row at index 1 the Current
 dataGrid.CurrentRowIndex = 1;
```

Something similar in a DataGridView:
<sub>(One of the methods that can be used to achieve this result)</sub>

```
// Move the focus and selects the Row at index 1
dataGridView.Rows[1].Selected = true;
// Make the Row at index 1 the Current setting the CurrentCell property
dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 
                                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2].Index;
```